# MATLAB: Adding vectors to a matrix and counting the number of non zeros

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following problem:

```
A = [] % matrix
Q = [] % number on non zero in each row 

for i=1:10  
% I generate a path with name path 
% add the path to the matrix A  
end
% count number on non zero numbers in each row
```

How can I do that?

Here is an illustrative example:

1. If the path in first iteration was: `path = [ 1 2 3 4 ]`
2. In the second iteration: `path = [ 4 5 6 ]`
3. In third iteration: `path = [ 7 2 ]`

Then A should be like this:

```
 A = 
   [1 2 3 4 ,
    4 5 6 0 ,
    7 2 0 0 ]
```

After, I would like a vector to show me the number of numbers different than zero in each row like so:

```
Q = [4 3 2]
```

Comment: Some comments before I answer your question as this will dictate how the solution will be written.  1) How are these "paths" stored or generated? Are they in a cell array? Another matrix? Read from file? If they're generated, how are you generating them? 2) Do you **have** to use a `for` loop? Depending on how you answer (1), we can escape `for` loops all together.

Comment: (1)They are generated in another for loop and they are saved in array like this path = [path i]... I didn't mention because it is a complex code.. but I know that it is an array.. (2) yes for each iteration, we have to generate paths actually not one path.. but I am working in generating one path for each iteration

Comment: Alright, give me 5 minutes to work on a solution

Comment: Finished.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comments, this is what I would suggest that you do:

1. Because the actual paths are not known *a priori*, I would suggest that you store all of the paths in a cell array.  Given your `for` loop condition, I'm assuming that there will be 10 paths.  The actual paths we don't know, but we know there will be 10.
2. Write some code that will figure out **the maximum length of path** as this will dictate the size of our matrix `A`.
3. Create the matrix `A` then store of all the paths in, with zeroes appended at the end of each path should they not be the size of the maximum length of the path.
4. Using the matrix `A`, figure out how many non-zeroes there are.

Without any further ado, here is the code you are seeking.  With each step, I will explain what I am doing to get the desired step.

### Step #1

```
pathCellArray = cell(10, 1);
for i = 1 : 10
   %// Insert path generation code here...
   %// Assume that the variable is called
   %// 'path' that stores this path
   %//..
   pathCellArray{i} = path;
end
```

This should be self-explanatory.  For each path that you generate, store it in its corresponding cell.  The reason why we are placing each path in a cell is because the length of each path is variable.  We are also doing this so we can figure out how many columns we need to allocate for `A`.  Also take note that I am creating a `cell` array of **columns**.  The reason why is because when we do a reconstruction and solve for `A`, it will make things easier.

### Step #2

```
%// Use cellfun that takes in a cell array and we will
%// generate an array as output that contains the
%// size of each path.  We will find the maximum of 
%// all of these that will dictate our size of A
lengthArray = cellfun(@length, pathCellArray);
numCols = max(lengthArray);
```

Now this is something cool.  You probably have never seen `cellfun` before.  How `cellfun` works is that we specify a custom function, and `cellfun` will apply this function to **every** element to this cell.  For the output of `cellfun` the i'th position of the output is the output of the custom function for each i'th position of the input cell array.  As such, what we are doing here is that we are generating a length array (stored as `lengthArray`) that goes through each cell and figures out how big the path is.  `lengthArray` will thus store how long each path is.  Once we do that, we figure out what the **longest** path is so we know how big `A` will be.

### Step #3

```
pathCellArrayAppend = cellfun(@(x) [x zeros(1,numCols-length(x))], ...
                              pathCellArray, 'UniformOutput', false);

A = cell2mat(pathCellArrayAppend);
```

This code is probably the most complex out of all that you have dealt with.  What I am basically doing here is taking that `cell` array of paths that I created, and generating a new cell array where each element in the cell (which is our path) gets appended with zeroes up until the length of the **longest** path.  If you look, the custom function we have generated basically creates the array that first stores the path that we want, then zero-pads the rest of the array with zeroes.  We have to specify `UniformOutput` to false as because the output of the the custom function is **no longer** a single value.  It is an array as the output, which is why this flag is set to false.  The output of this call to `cellfun` will generate 10 cell arrays where each element is a path and is zero-padded with zeroes.  We then call `cell2mat` to convert this cell array back to matrix form, and `A` is your result.

### Step #4

```
Q = cellfun(@(x) sum(x ~= 0), pathCellArrayAppend);
```

We thus call `cellfun` again.  This time we take a look at our cell array that has all of the paths that are zero-padded.  We go through each cell, and count how many non-zero entries there are.  `Q` will store this result.  Note that we don't need to set `UniformOutput` to false as the output of the custom function is a single number.

---

Using your example that you have provided, here is how the code will look with their corresponding outputs:

```
%// Step #1 - Simulated
p1 = [1 2 3 4];
p2 = [4 5 6];
p3 = [7 2];
pathCellArray = {p1; p2; p3};

%// Step #2
lengthArray = cellfun(@length, pathCellArray)

>> lengthArray =

  4
  3
  2

numCols = max(lengthArray)

>> numCols =

    4

%// Step #3
pathCellArrayAppend = cellfun(@(x) [x zeros(1,numCols-length(x))], ...
                          pathCellArray, 'UniformOutput', false);

A = cell2mat(pathCellArrayAppend)

>> A =

 1     2     3     4
 4     5     6     0
 7     2     0     0

%// Step #4
Q = cellfun(@(x) sum(x ~= 0), pathCellArrayAppend)

>> Q =

 4
 3
 2
```

**NB:**  You could simply use Step #2 as your `Q`, provided that your paths are **non-zero**.  If there are, then you need to go right to Step #4.

Comment: @TravellingSalesWoman: Do you require any further assistance?